# Paypal gateway is not working in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

Paypal payment method is not working on my production environment.
I am getting below error:

`PayPal gateway has rejected request. Invalid token (#10410: Invalid token)`

Environment details:

```
      magento 1.9
      Php version 5.6
      Server Nginx
```

Kindly provide the solution for resolving the error on my production server.

Comment: Did you check your paypal credentials?

Comment: Hi, Above problem was coming because redirection code was missing from code.
Thanks for supporting

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this error during checkout? If yes - to solve this issue please check the link below. There is a fix you have to make.

https://github.com/varinen/Solvingmagento_OneStepCheckout/pull/3/commits/702b05b9ec78854f236b3f004ade498747e8afaf